# Animated glow/flash of UIButton text

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a UIButton set as a custom button with button.TitleLabel.text set with some text.
This makes it look just like a label that can be pressed.

I'd like to have an animated glow on the text, so it draws the attention of the user.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the RRSGlowLabel class. It extends UILabel, but you could find it useful to.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I've had a look, and will test it tomorrow. It might work. I could use text with a transparent button over the top.
It's just a case of whether I can animate the glow to pulse.

Comment: The text in a UIButton *is* a UILabel -- it has a property for accessing it. So anything you can do with a label you can do with a button. Please don't bring us back to the days of HTML <BLINK> with your newfound powers, though. :)

Comment: Haha, no no blinking. Just a very subtle pulsing glow. So am I right in thinking I can create a UILabel *label = .... (or in this case an RSSGlowLabel) then just set mybutton.titlelabel = label?

Comment: rickster, I don't think there is way to assign the RRSGlowLable (or UILable) to a button.